# Exit Excel If Incorrect File Is Opened

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I want to create a prompt in Excel for the user to select and open a file. However, at the same time I also want to make sure that the user is selecting the correct file. The excel should exit in either of the cases.

1. No file is selected.
2. Or Incorrect file is selected.

I have the following code that fulfills the first requirement but need some assistance on the second one.

```
Dim strFileToOpen As Variant
strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please Choose Missing Charges File To Open")
If strFileToOpen = False Then
MsgBox "No File Selected. Program Will Exit.", vbExclamation, "Oops!"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Quit
Exit Sub
Else
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen
MsgBox "Thanks For Selecting The Correct File", vbExclamation, "Thanks!"
End If
```

Comment: You need to supply a pattern that the selected filename can be checked against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub correctAnswer()

Dim strFileToOpen As Variant

**Dim correctFileName As String**

**correctFileName = "Put your intended file name here"**

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _

(Title:="Please Choose Missing Charges File To Open")

If strFileToOpen = False **Or strFileToOpen <> correctFileName** Then

MsgBox "No/Wrong File Selected. Program Will Exit.", vbExclamation, "Oops!"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Application.Quit

Exit Sub

Else

Workbooks.Open Filename:=strFileToOpen

MsgBox "Thanks For Selecting The Correct File", vbExclamation, "Thanks!"

End If

End Sub

Comment: You need to tell the computer which is the correct file name.

Comment: I believe it may be more like a 'pattern' that can be dissected. e.g *starts with* the word(s) *Daily_Charges_* and ends with a date that can be compared to yesterday or the last business day. The OP needs to clarify this but perhaps he can work from your sample code.

Comment: Well, I told my computer the correct file name but not it exiting the program even if I am selecting the correct. My file name is "MissingCharges.xlsx". I defined it as `correctFileName = "MissingCharges.xlsx"`.

Comment: I got it now. I have define the entire path along with the filename in `correctFileName`.

Comment: Hey apologies for the slow reply. Yea glad you got it - you need the full path. Hope it helps anyway!